# View resizes in iPhone 6/6 PLUS (wrong size)

Tags: ios, xcode, size, iphone-6

[image]

When switching to Xcode 7 i experienced some problems with iPhone 6/6plus screen sizes. I had an iPhone 4-sized view with black bars on top and bottom of it.
I read that i had to load appropriate launch images so I did it. The bars disappeared but the only views that scaled properly were the Tab bar and status bar (with wrong launch images i managed to fill the whole screen but the status bar was zoomed). The whole content stays 'windowed' and I don't know how to change it. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use proper autolayouts Or Autoresizing Properties to make it look good on all the Devices.